# Ocaml- partial derivative of a regular expression

Tags: algorithm, types, ocaml

I got this code:

```
type regexp =
  | V                      (* void                      *)
  | E                      (* epsilon                   *)
  | C of char              (* char                      *)
  | U of regexp * regexp   (* a + b                     *)
  | P of regexp * regexp   (* a.b                       *)
  | S of regexp            (* a*                        *)
;;

...
module ReS = Set.Make (struct
  type t = regexp
  let compare = compare
  end)
(* module/type for pairs of sets of regular expressions *)
module RePS = Set.Make (struct
  type t = ReS.t * ReS.t
  let compare = compare
  end)
(*module/type for set of chars *)
module CS = Set.Make(Char)

let ewps = ReS.exists ewp;;
let atmost_epsilons = ReS.for_all atmost_epsilon;;
let infinitys = ReS.exists infinity;;

let rigth_concat s = function
| V -> ReS.empty
| E -> s
| r -> ReS.map (fun e -> P (e,r)) s
;;
let ( *.* ) = rigth_concat;;

(* partial derivative of a regular expression *)
let rec pd a re = function
  | V | E -> ReS.empty
  | C  b when b=a -> ReS.singleton E
  | C  b -> ReS.empty
  | U (r, s) -> ReS.union (pd a r) (pd a s)
  | P (r, s) when ewp a -> ReS.union ((pd a r) *.* s) (pd a s)
  | P (r, s) -> (pd a r) *.* s
  | S r as re -> (pd a r) *.* re
;;
let rec unions f s =
  ReS.fold (fun re acc -> ReS.union (f re) acc ) s ReS.empty
;;
let rec pds a s = unions (pd a) s;;

let rec pdw (sr: ReS.t) = function
  | [] -> sr
  | a::tl -> pds a (pdw sr tl)
;;
```

I checked the types of return values and i think they are correct, but it returns the following error and I am not sure why.

> This expression has type regexp -> ReS.t but an expression was
>   expected of type ReS.t

In function "pd" in line that has error

```
| U (r, s) -> ReS.union (pd a r) (pd a s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is caused by the fact that `function` supplies an implicit parameter. This expression:

```
function None -> 0 | Some x -> x
```

is a function with *one* parameter. So in your case you have defined `pd` to have three parameters. It looks to me like you're expecting it to have two parameters.

You can probably change your `function ...` to `match re with` instead. Or you can remove the explicit `re` parameter, and use the parameter that's implicit in `function`.

Comment: i only remove the tag "function" and enter "match re with"?

Comment: Yes, that should work. You can also just remove "re" on the first line. Note btw that you're not using this parameter `re` anywhere in the code right now.